# Yarn cache is getting duplicate after each yarn add or yarn install

Tags: yarnpkg

I have an issue with yarn install and yarn add because every time that I need to run yarn add or yarn install the yarn cache is getting duplicating and maybe my node module what is wrong with it ? how can I solve this problem ?

I have to clean yarn cache and delete node module every time I need to yarn install or yarn add, I don't like to do this.
Yarn version : 1.22.19

Comment: Qoraish Have you found a solution to your problem?